# Input Stream Reader with multi-line text file

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, file-io, jtextarea

My program can't read a txt file that is in a multi-line format. The content of the text file should be printed inside a textArea but when it comes to multi-lined files nothing happens. Also I would like to prompt a message : "File Existed" when a file exists, and "File not found" when a file don't exist.

Here's my code :

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    String sCurrentLine;

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\theBeard\\workspace\\LeapYear\\"+textField.getText()));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        textArea.setText(sCurrentLine);
    }
        br.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

also , is this method the correct to check if a file exists?

```
try {

                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\theBeard\\workspace\\LeapYear\\"+textField.getText()));
                textArea.read(br, textArea);//this was a suggestion     by     someone below


                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {



                     textArea.append(sCurrentLine);
                     textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)
                    {

                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. everything is crystal clear. :)

Comment: one more little thing guys ,if I would like to prompt a message saying the file wasn't found, where should I put it ? thanks!

Comment: If you have new question post it in new question. There are at least two reasons for that: (1) not many people will read your comment and this additional question now (2) it is not related to problem you are currently having.

Comment: oh, okay. but the page says, I should wait for 2 more days before asking again. but thanks for your help sir, and the others who answered. very much appreciated!

Comment: That is strange. Did you ask questions which later ware downvoted/closed and deleted?

Comment: no sir, its my first time to post here, 2nd time actually.

Answer (score 3):

`textArea.setText(sCurrentLine);` doesn't *add* text to area, but *replaces it* with new text. So your code will set text to last line from your text file. So if your last line is empty you will not see anything.

What you may want to use is `append` method.

Also you are not closing your resources in right place, since it should be done only in finally block. Consider using try-with-resources which will handle it for you.

So try with something like

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader("C:\\Users\\theBeard\\workspace\\LeapYear\\"+ textField.getText()))) {
    String sCurrentLine;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        textArea.append(sCurrentLine);
        textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: uhm, one more thing, I would like to prompt a message saying :"File not found.", where should I put it? thanks!

Comment: You could handle it in many ways. You could first try creating `Path` to that file, and then test if such path points to proper file for instance via `Files.exist(path)`. If file exist then continue with code, if not ask for proper file location. We could also handle `NoSuchFileException` but this is usually bad decision because exceptions shouldn't be part of standard logic, but they should handle exceptional situations which we ware not able to prevent.

Comment: @mKorbel That is very nice method. You should post it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Append the text instead of setting it for every iteration

```
textArea.append(sCurrentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: @mKorbel yeah that would be far simpler or course :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setText(String t)
```

> Sets the text of this TextComponent to the specified text. If the text
>   is null or empty, has the effect of simply deleting the old text.

`textArea.setText(sCurrentLine)` overwrites the entire text of the text area for every line. If your last line in the file is an emtpy line, your text area will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your last line is empty, the only thing that will be set is this empty line, since you always overwrite the text in your text area. I would suggest using a StringBuilder to read the whole file into...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
... read via BufferedReader
sb.append( sCurrentLine );

...set whole text...
textArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    textArea.setText(sCurrentLine);
}
```

This over-writes the existing value everytime, so you end up only having the last line value.

Get the previous value and then append to it.

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String x = textArea.getText().toString();
    textArea.setText(x + sCurrentLine);
}
```